# how to turn our PC to a webserver that uses tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, xampp, dsl, router

I'm trying to make my PC become a webserver using tomcat. The last time I did it was 6 months ago, and I totally did it. However, I couldn't do it this time. my steps are:

- set static IP by go to Local area network properties and go to TCP/IP 4, check use the following IP address and input :

[image]

- open browser and type 192.168.1.1 to access DSL router, to NAT and input like following

[image]

- go to ip2location.com to see my router ip address. Then on my phone browser (using 3G, not the same line with my computer), I enter the ip address + port 8080 + / + myproject name. It displays not found.

[image]

I also have xampp, and I usually turn it off to access to tomcat server except this time. 
:(

Comment: looks like you are forwarding port 80, not port 8080. what port is tomcat running on? do you mean to forward the routers port 80 to 8080 on your tomcat machine?

Comment: yes, at xampp, if I set 80 to both external and internal, it could run immediately, and as I remembered in the past, I do the same thing to run tomcat server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The page displayed is probably being served by your router.

You configured your router to redirect all incoming requests on port `80` (external) to the machine with IP `192.168.1.2` at port `80` (internal). On the other hand your phone is making a request to your router on port `8080`.

I suggest setting `8080` for both "Internal Port Start" and "Internal Port End" and requesting your pages on your phone without the port, i.e., just with your external IP you got from ip2location.